# Как собрать Telegram desktop версию?

Tags: qt5

Telegram desktop версия написана на qt5. У кого нибудь получилось его собрать? Поделитесь опытом, как это сделать.

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали при сборке? Скажем, читали ли вы "Build instructions" из репозитория? Там есть инструкции для сборки в Visual Studio, Xcode, Qt Creator и ещё много чего.

Answer (score 8):

1. Не используйте master. Текущий коммит не собирается. Используйте теги, последняя стабильная версия [v0.9.48](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/releases/tag/v0.9.48)
2. Telegram использует патченную версию Qt. Собрать с системной или скачанной с сайта не получится. Нужно собирать свою версию, патч в репозитории Telegram прилагается.
3. В директории [.travis](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/tree/v0.9.48/.travis) находятся скрипты сборки, где всё расписано по шагам, включая сборку Qt. Можно использовать для сборки непосредственно их.
4. В файле [.travis.yml](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/v0.9.48/.travis.yml) указаны все зависимости, которые необходимо поставить для сборки.

Comment: Это все конечно интересно, но как собрать Telegram?

Comment: @Cerbo запустить `.travis/build.sh`